# Selection of user's vote column based on ID

Tags: mysql, sql, join

In my public voting database, I have pages and pages_votes tables with structure below:-
**Page**
[image: page table]

**Page Votes** 
[image]

i am querying mysql database to get results for all pages with their total sum of  positive and negative votes
positive vote is 1, and negative vote is 0.
my query is as below:-

```
SELECT pages.id, pages.title, COUNT(pv.page_id) AS `total_count`, SUM(pv.vote=1) AS `likes`, SUM(pv.vote=0) AS `dislikes` 
FROM `pages` 
LEFT JOIN `pages_votes` AS `pv` ON `pages`.`id` = `pv`.`page_id` 
GROUP BY `pages`.`id`, `pages`.`title`, `pages`.`slug`, `pages`.`image` 
ORDER BY `total_count` DESC;
```

Results look like this (no issue here):-
[image]

Now I want to include a new custom column in this result called **'my_vote'**, my vote will show me my votes (user_id = 3) as 1 or 0 for like/dislikes if i have voted, and NULL if i have not voted. 
There is already a user_id in page_votes table recording which user voted. How do I use that to get votes of a specific user with say ID = 10?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. try `GROUP BY pages.id, pages.title`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest writing your query with table aliases.  Then the answer to your question is a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, COUNT(pv.page_id) AS total_count,
       SUM(pv.vote =1 ) AS likes, SUM(pv.vote = 0) AS dislikes,
       SUM(CASE WHEN pv.vote = 1 AND p.user_id = 3 THEN 1
                WHEN pv.vote = 0 AND p.user_id = 3 THEN 0
           END) as user_3_vote
FROM pages p LEFT JOIN 
     pages_votes pv
     ON  p.id = pv.page_id 
GROUP BY p.id, p.title
ORDER BY total_count DESC;
```

Note that this uses `SUM(CASE . . .)` rather than `SUM( <boolean expression> )`.  This is important so you can get a `NULL` value when there is no vote.

Answer (score 0):

will you consider a small change here in your query? to get specified output.

```
SELECT pages.id, pages.title, COUNT(pv.page_id) AS `total_count`, 
SUM(case when pv.vote = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS `likes`, 
SUM(case when pv.vote = 0 then 1 else 0 end) AS `dislikes`
FROM `pages`
LEFT JOIN `pages_votes` AS `pv`
ON `pages`.`id` = `pv`.`page_id`
GROUP BY `pages`.`id`, `pages`.`title`, `pages`.`slug`, `pages`.`image`
ORDER BY `total_count` DESC;
```